# Unwanted Paramters in Swagger UI + Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I am seeing a lot of unwanted fields being shown in swagger ui for a spring boot app.

MY swagger dependencies are

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
```

See attached screenshot
[image]

My Rest Controller code is something like this

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "Get Data")
    @GetMapping(value = "/applicant", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> getApplicant(@Valid  ApplicantRequestBean 
    applicantRequestBean, Errors errors) throws APIValidationException {
     if (errors.hasErrors()) {
     //check for constraintsviolation here and throw an error if found
     throw new APIValidationException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Bad Request", errorWrapper);
     }

}
```

My ApplicationRequestBean has

```
    @NotBlank(message = "Id is mandatory")
    @Size(min = 9, max = 9, message = "Id should be 9 characters long")
    @ApiModelProperty(example = "@12345678", value = "Applicant Id", position = 3)
    private String id=null;
    @NotBlank(message = "Date of Birth is mandatory")
    @ApiModelProperty(example = "30-12-2000", value = "Applicant Date of Birth in DD-MM-YYYY format",  position = 2)
    private String dateOfBirth=null;
    @Email
    @ApiModelProperty(example = "id@domain.com", value = "Applicant Email Id", position = 1)
    private String emailId=null;
    @ApiModelProperty(example = "971505504XXX", value = "Applicant Contact Number", position = 0)
    private String contactNumber=null;
```

My APIValidationException class extends RuntimeException and has three fields

```
private HttpStatus status;
private String message;
private Object errors;
```

My CustomExceptionHandler which extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler is like this

@RestControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler
{

```
 @ExceptionHandler(APIValidationException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleAPIValidationExceptions(APIValidationException ex, WebRequest request) {
        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse("error", ex.getMessage(), ex.getErrors());
        return new ResponseEntity(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

Lastly MySwaager Config is like this

```
public Docket swaggerConfiguration() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .groupName(swaggerGroupName)
                .select()
                .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/**"))
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("a.b.c.d"))
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .tags(new Tag("Applicant", "Applicant APIs"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I need the Errors but the way to solve it is by adding

.ignoredParameterTypes(Errors.class) to the Swagger Config

and @ApiParam(hidden = true) before the error parameter in RestController

Comment: Using error in not good way actually and handling  constraintsviolation exception so you don't need error then in controller, but it depends on you.

Comment: well i want to send the exceptions raised from Contraints Violation but the error object needs to be in custom format. This is the only way i could make it work. Is there a better alternative ?

Comment: Yes you can handle in ExceptionHandler and modify the error object

Comment: CustomViolationException is handled by Exception class in the ExcpetionHandler so i have to then check for the typeof and if it CVE then work on it...isnt it ?

Comment: Yes, I added an example in answer , you can check her for defails https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-rest-validation-example/